# Is it possible to call login.microsoftonline.com from javascript to get Bearer Token without using node.js

Tags: javascript, azure, request, token

I'm trying to call login.microsoftonline.com/xxx/oauth2/token from a javascript client to get a Bearer Token. But when i'm doing my request I always get a error 400 Bad Request without any information. When doing my request in Postman everything works and I get my Bearer Token, but when trying it in my javascript client I'm getting this error.
I read about using the msal.js library but as I understand I need to use a node.js server to use the library to access the azure ad. In my environment I do not have the opportunity to set up a node.js server to use the library.

I tried to use following code in my javascript client:

```
var myHeaders = new Headers();
myHeaders.append("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
myHeaders.append("Cookie", "esctx=XXX; fpc=XXX; stsservicecookie=estsfd; x-ms-gateway-slice=estsfd");

var urlencoded = new URLSearchParams();
urlencoded.append("grant_type", "client_credentials");
urlencoded.append("client_id", "XXX");
urlencoded.append("client_secret", "XXX");
urlencoded.append("resource", "XXX");

var requestOptions = {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: myHeaders,
  body: urlencoded,
  redirect: 'follow'
};

fetch("https://login.microsoftonline.com/XXX/oauth2/token", requestOptions)
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(result => console.log(result))
  .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
```

But using this give me a bad request error. The code was generated by postman based on my working request in postman. Maybe is there anything else i need to know about calling the azure ad bearer token from client side? Is there anything different to calling it from postman?

Thank you for your help. If you need any further information I will add it.

Comment: MSAL.js is a client side library that runs in browser, it does **not** need nodejs at runtime. For your development, you need node js and npm for `local` web server and debugging, that does not mean MSAL needs nodejs server. Go with MSAL and save yourself lot of pain.

Comment: could u tell me how I import the msal library in javascript?

Answer (score 0):

As Anand mentioned, MSAL (Microsoft Authentication Library) is available for use cases such as your own.

You can find it [here](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js). The linked Github repo also provides [examples](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/tree/dev/lib/msal-browser).

Hopefully this helps you with implementing the MSAL library to perform oauth in javascript.

Kind regards